# An generic EventManager - stuck after 3 lines of code :-)

Tags: java, android, events, generics

I am soooo close, but I don't get my head wrapped around it.

I am trying to create an event manager in Java (Android) with the default stuff, like register for events, raise events, and so on...

I want this to be "generic" in a way that I can write something like this:

```
StringChangedEvent event 
       = evManInst.Register<StringChangedEvent>(new StringChangedEvent());
event.Publish("Hello");
```

And in a different class

```
StringChangedEvent event 
       = evManInst.Register<StringChangedEvent>(new StringChangedEvent());
event.Subscribe(this)
```

Of course, the instance should be the same one. I have to pass the object, because I cant new T() - but maybe I am doing something really evil with generics here :-)

If you read the implemenation of my EventManager, the **first return line wont compile**, because of incompatible types. How do I solve this? The funny thing is, if you look at the code, its all pretty ok regarding types, there is nothing which can go wrong (in my opinion).

One more point: **I dont want to create a generic** `EventManager<StringChangedEvent>` because this would limit this EventManager to one type of events. And returning the `EventBase` and casting it just is ugly (but perhaps the only way to go?).

```
  public class EventManager
    {
        private HashMap<Class<EventBase>, EventBase> _registeredEvents 
          = new HashMap<Class<EventBase>, EventBase>();

        public<T extends EventBase> T Register(T instance)
        {
        if (_registeredEvents.containsKey(instance.getClass()))
        {
            return _registeredEvents.get(instance.getClass());
        }
        else
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT To clarify comment on answer from Kaediil**

```
EventManager x = new EventManager<TestEvent>();
EventManager x2 = new EventManager();

// Not OK
TestEvent t = x.Register(new TestEvent());

// OK (but I want MORE :-)
TestEvent t2 = (TestEvent)x.Register(new TestEvent());

// This to be exact, because then I can do something like this
TestEvent t2 = x.Register<TestEvent>(new TestEvent());

x.Register<TestEvent>(new TestEvent()).CallMethodOfTestEvent();
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Incompatible types. He want me to return T, and he seems not to get that the instance is of type T.

Comment: The Java syntax for the last two calls is `x.<TestEvent>Register`, and you should almost never have to use it. Sometimes the type inference algorithm doesn't do what you expect and it's useful, but usually it just means your API uses way too much generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you want:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class EventManager {

    private HashMap<Class<? extends EventBase>, EventBase> _registeredEvents
            = new HashMap<Class<? extends EventBase>, EventBase>();


    public <T extends EventBase> T Register(T event) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<? extends T> eventType = (Class<? extends T>) event.getClass();

        if (_registeredEvents.containsKey(eventType)) {
            return eventType.cast(_registeredEvents.get(eventType));
        } else {
            _registeredEvents.put(eventType, event);
            return event;
        }
    }
}

class EventBase {}

class ChangeEvent extends EventBase {}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventManager em = new EventManager();
        ChangeEvent e = em.Register(new ChangeEvent());
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the line following the `@SuppressWarnings`, but I think it should be correct, and it's just the compiler magic around `getClass()` that doesn't handle this correctly.

The problem in your code was that you can't retrieve something else than `EventBase` from a `HashMap<…, EventBase>` because there's no way to statically prove this is typesafe. You have to cast somewhere, and `Class.cast` lets you do this in the implementation of the method. (You could also cast to `T` to "make the compiler shut up", but that's a bad idea because it makes ClassCastExceptions happen in code using your API instead of where the cast is.)

Comment: Oh I love this page :-) Works perfectly, and I even dont need the <> on the function (that was a mistake from me, in C# you do it, and I just guessed the Java syntax...)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class EventManager <T extends EventBase>{

private HashMap<Class<EventBase>, T > _registeredEvents 
= new HashMap<Class<EventBase>, T>();



public T Register( T instance)
{
    if (_registeredEvents.containsKey(instance.getClass()))
    {
        return  _registeredEvents.get(instance.getClass());
    }
    else
    {
        return instance;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only gets me half the way. I know I am a bitchy little girl, but I want (t) to work, t2 is too long :-) See above edited code at the end... x or x2 dont make a difference, btw.

Comment: @Christian: You need to declare the variable (in your edit) as `EventManager<TestEvent> x = new EventManager<TestEvent>();`, not as the raw type.

Comment: Ok, but this would still get me stuck with a single eventManager for every event type I need, or am I wrong? The idea is to have only one for all, I might have to stick to the cast - its not THAT bad, I just wanted to know if I am just not getting generics right...

Comment: @Christian: Yeah, I just figured out what you meant. See my answer.